# Finding each centroid of multiple connected objects

Tags: python, image-processing, image-segmentation, opencv, centroid

I am SUPER new to python coding and would like some help. I was able to segment each cell outline within a biological tissue (super cool!) and now I am trying to find the centroid of each cell within a tissue using this:

[image]

I am using this code:

```
img = cv2.imread('/Users/kate/Desktop/SegmenterTest/SegmentedCells/Seg1.png')
image = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
thresh = cv2.threshold(image, 60, 255, cv2.THRESH_BINARY)[1]

cnts = cv2.findContours(thresh.copy(), cv2.RETR_EXTERNAL, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)
cnts = imutils.grab_contours(cnts)

# loop over the contours
for c in cnts:
    # compute the center of the contour
    M = cv2.moments(c)
    cX = int(M["m10"] / M["m00"])
    cY = int(M["m01"] / M["m00"])
    # draw the contour and center of the shape on the image
    cv2.drawContours(image, [c], -1, (0, 255, 0), 2)
    cv2.circle(image, (cX, cY), 7, (255, 255, 255), -1)
    cv2.putText(image, "center", (cX - 20, cY - 20),
        cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_SIMPLEX, 0.5, (255, 255, 255), 2)
    # show the image
    cv2.imshow("Image", image)
    cv2.waitKey(0)
```

However,  when I use this code, it is giving me the centroid of the ENTIRE object, and not each individual object to give this.

[image]

I have no idea where to go from here, so a nudge in the right direction would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the function [regionprops](https://scikit-image.org/docs/dev/api/skimage.measure.html#regionprops) from the module scikit-image in your case. Here is what I got.

[image: Centroids of cells]

This is the code I used.

```
import cv2
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from skimage import measure
import numpy as np

cells = cv2.imread('cells.png',0)

ret,thresh = cv2.threshold(cells,20,255,cv2.THRESH_BINARY_INV)


labels= measure.label(thresh, background=0)
bg_label = labels[0,0] 
labels[labels==bg_label] = 0 # Assign background label to 0

props = measure.regionprops(labels)

fig,ax = plt.subplots(1,1)
plt.axis('off')
ax.imshow(cells,cmap='gray')
centroids = np.zeros(shape=(len(np.unique(labels)),2)) # Access the coordinates of centroids
for i,prop in enumerate(props):
    my_centroid = prop.centroid
    centroids[i,:]= my_centroid
    ax.plot(my_centroid[1],my_centroid[0],'r.')

# print(centroids)
# fig.savefig('out.png', bbox_inches='tight', pad_inches=0)
plt.show()
```

Good luck with your research!

Comment: Your welcome! I would appreciate it if you can mark my answer as the correct answer!

Comment: Hi again, So the code worked perfectly when I used it for the previous image, but when I switched images to something more complex it gave me both the centroids of the black AND white images regions, even though the white regions were only a few pixels wide. Any way I can only apply this to the black regions' outlines? Or to specify a minimum size that it will analyze?

Comment: You can specify a minimum size in the for loop by using 'prop.area' which returns the pixel number of each connected components. Please check the details at the function 'regionprops' I provided in the answer.

Answer (score 1):

**Problem**

`cv2.findContours` uses an algorithm which has a few different 'retrieval modes'. These affect which contours are returned and how they are returned. This is documented [here](https://docs.opencv.org/3.4/d3/dc0/group__imgproc__shape.html#ga819779b9857cc2f8601e6526a3a5bc71). These are given as the second argument to `findContours`. Your code uses `cv2.RETR_EXTERNAL` which means `findContours` will only return the outermost border of separate objects.

**Solution**

Changing this argument to `cv2.RETR_LIST` will give you all the contours in the image (including the one outermost border). This is the simplest solution.

E.g.

```
import cv2
import imutils

img = cv2.imread('/Users/kate/Desktop/SegmenterTest/SegmentedCells/Seg1.png')
image = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
thresh = cv2.threshold(image, 60, 255, cv2.THRESH_BINARY)[1]

cnts = cv2.findContours(thresh.copy(), cv2.RETR_LIST, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)
cnts = imutils.grab_contours(cnts)

# loop over the contours
for c in cnts:
    # compute the center of the contour
    M = cv2.moments(c)
    cX = int(M["m10"] / M["m00"])
    cY = int(M["m01"] / M["m00"])
    # draw the contour and center of the shape on the image
    cv2.drawContours(image, [c], -1, (0, 255, 0), 2)
    cv2.circle(image, (cX, cY), 7, (255, 255, 255), -1)
    cv2.putText(image, "center", (cX - 20, cY - 20),
        cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_SIMPLEX, 0.5, (255, 255, 255), 2)
    # show the image
    cv2.imshow("Image", image)
    cv2.waitKey(0)
```

**Selecting only the innermost objects**

To reliably omit the outer contours you can take advantage of the ability of `findContours` to return a hierarchy of the contours it detects. To do this, you can change the retrieval mode argument once again to `RETR_TREE`, which will generate a full hierarchy.

The hierarchy is an array containing arrays of 4 values for each contour in the image. Each value is an index of a contour in the contour array. From the [docs](https://docs.opencv.org/3.4/d3/dc0/group__imgproc__shape.html#ga17ed9f5d79ae97bd4c7cf18403e1689a):

> For each i-th contour `contours[i]`, the elements `hierarchy[i][0]` ,
> `hierarchy[i][1]` , `hierarchy[i][2]`, and `hierarchy[i][3]` are set to
> 0-based indices in contours of the next and previous contours at the
> same hierarchical level, the first child contour and the parent
> contour, respectively. If for the contour i there are no next,
> previous, parent, or nested contours, the corresponding elements of
> `hierarchy[i]` will be negative.

When we say 'innermost', what we mean is contours that have no children (contours inside of them). So we want those contours whose entry in the hierarchy has a negative 3rd value. That is,  `contours[i]`, such that `hierarchy[i][2] < 0`

A small wrinkle is that although `findContours` returns a tuple which includes the hierarchy, `imutils.grabContours` discards the hierarchy and returns just the array of contours. All this means is that we have to do the work of `grabContours` ourselves, if we intend on working with different versions of OpenCV. This is just a simple `if else` statement.

```
res = cv2.findContours(thresh.copy(), cv2.RETR_TREE, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)

# switch for different versions of OpenCV
if len(cnts) == 3:
    _, cnts, hierarchy = res
else:
    cnts, hierarchy = res
```

Once you have `hierarchy`, checking if a contour, `cnts[i]` is 'innermost' can be done with `hierarchy[0][i][2] < 0`, which should be `False` for contours that contain other contours.

A full example based on your question's code:

```
import cv2
import imutils

img = cv2.imread('/Users/kate/Desktop/SegmenterTest/SegmentedCells/Seg1.png')
image = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
thresh = cv2.threshold(image, 60, 255, cv2.THRESH_BINARY)[1]

cnts = cv2.findContours(thresh.copy(), cv2.RETR_TREE, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)

# switch for different versions of OpenCV
if len(cnts) == 3:
    _, cnts, hierarchy = cnts
else:
    cnts, hierarchy = cnts

# loop over the contours
for i, c in enumerate(cnts):
    # check that it is 'innermost'
    if hierarchy[0][i][2] < 0:
        # compute the center of the contour
        M = cv2.moments(c)
        cX = int(M["m10"] / M["m00"])
        cY = int(M["m01"] / M["m00"])

        # draw the contour and center of the shape on the image
        cv2.drawContours(image, [c], -1, (0, 255, 0), 2)
        cv2.circle(image, (cX, cY), 7, (255, 255, 255), -1)
        cv2.putText(image, "center", (cX - 20, cY - 20),
                    cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_SIMPLEX, 0.5, (255, 255, 255), 2)
        # show the image
        cv2.imshow("Image", image)
        cv2.waitKey(0)
```

Comment: is there any way I can get only the cells? I find when I change to RETR_LIST it gives all the contours AND the outermost, but how can I get the innermost? Thanks!!

Comment: @helpkate1991 I have updated my answer with a discussion on the 'hierarchy' of contours.