# Python/OpenCV — Intelligent Centroid Tracking in Bacterial Images?

Tags: python, python-3.x, opencv, image-processing, computer-vision

I'm currently working on an algorithm to detect bacterial centroids in microscopy images.

This question is a continuation of: OpenCV/Python — Matching Centroid Points of Bacteria in Two Images: [Python/OpenCV — Matching Centroid Points of Bacteria in Two Images](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62982967/python-opencv-matching-centroid-points-of-bacteria-in-two-images)

I am using a modified version of the program proposed by Rahul Kedia.
https://stackoverflow.com/a/63049277/13696853

Currently, the issues in segmentation I am working on are:

1. Low Contrast
2. Clustering

The images below are sampled a second apart. However, in the latter image, one of the bacteria does not get detected.

[Bright-field Image #1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jcl1o.png)
[image: Bright-field Image #1]

[Bright-Field Image #2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NiqVQ.png)
[image: Bright-Field Image #2]

Bright-Field Contour Image #1
[image: 3]

Bright-Field Contour Image #2
[image: 4]

[Bright-Field Image #1 (Unsegmented)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BDyei.png)

[Bright-Field Image #2 (Unsegmented)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nwgFB.png)

I want to know, given that I can successfully determine bacterial centroids in an image, can I use the data to intelligently look for the same bacteria in the subsequent image?

I haven't been able to find anything substantial online; I believe SIFT/SURF would likely be ineffective as the bacteria have the same appearance. Moreover, I am looking for specific points in the images. You can view my program below. Insert a specific path as indicated if you'd like to run the program.

```
import cv2
import numpy as np
import os

kernel = np.array([[0, 0, 1, 0, 0],
                   [0, 1, 1, 1, 0],
                   [1, 1, 1, 1, 1],
                   [0, 1, 1, 1, 0],
                   [0, 0, 1, 0, 0]], dtype=np.uint8)


def e_d(image, it):
    image = cv2.erode(image, kernel, iterations=it)
    image = cv2.dilate(image, kernel, iterations=it)
    return image


path = r"[INSERT PATH]"
img_files = [file for file in os.listdir(path)]


def segment_index(index: int):
    segment_file(img_files[index])


def segment_file(img_file: str):
    img_path = path + "\\" + img_file
    print(img_path)
    img = cv2.imread(img_path)
    img = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
    # Applying adaptive mean thresholding
    th = cv2.adaptiveThreshold(img, 255, cv2.ADAPTIVE_THRESH_MEAN_C, cv2.THRESH_BINARY_INV, 11, 2)
    # Removing small noise
    th = e_d(th.copy(), 1)

    # Finding contours with RETR_EXTERNAL flag and removing undesired contours and
    # drawing them on a new image.
    cnt, hie = cv2.findContours(th, cv2.RETR_EXTERNAL, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_NONE)
    cntImg = th.copy()
    for contour in cnt:
        x, y, w, h = cv2.boundingRect(contour)
        # Eliminating the contour if its width is more than half of image width
        # (bacteria will not be that big).
        if w > img.shape[1] / 2:
            continue
        cntImg = cv2.drawContours(cntImg, [cv2.convexHull(contour)], -1, 255, -1)

    # Removing almost all the remaining noise.
    # (Some big circular noise will remain along with bacteria contours)
    cntImg = e_d(cntImg, 3)

    # Finding new filtered contours again
    cnt2, hie2 = cv2.findContours(cntImg, cv2.RETR_EXTERNAL, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_NONE)

    # Now eliminating circular type noise contours by comparing each contour's
    # extent of overlap with its enclosing circle.
    finalContours = []  # This will contain the final bacteria contours
    for contour in cnt2:
        # Finding minimum enclosing circle
        (x, y), radius = cv2.minEnclosingCircle(contour)
        center = (int(x), int(y))
        radius = int(radius)

        # creating a image with only this circle drawn on it(filled with white colour)
        circleImg = np.zeros(img.shape, dtype=np.uint8)
        circleImg = cv2.circle(circleImg, center, radius, 255, -1)

        # creating a image with only the contour drawn on it(filled with white colour)
        contourImg = np.zeros(img.shape, dtype=np.uint8)
        contourImg = cv2.drawContours(contourImg, [contour], -1, 255, -1)

        # White pixels not common in both contour and circle will remain white
        # else will become black.
        union_inter = cv2.bitwise_xor(circleImg, contourImg)

        # Finding ratio of the extent of overlap of contour to its enclosing circle.
        # Smaller the ratio, more circular the contour.
        ratio = np.sum(union_inter == 255) / np.sum(circleImg == 255)

        # Storing only non circular contours(bacteria)
        if ratio > 0.55:
            finalContours.append(contour)

    finalContours = np.asarray(finalContours)

    # Finding center of bacteria and showing it.
    bacteriaImg = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_GRAY2BGR)

    for bacteria in finalContours:
        M = cv2.moments(bacteria)
        cx = int(M['m10'] / M['m00'])
        cy = int(M['m01'] / M['m00'])

        bacteriaImg = cv2.circle(bacteriaImg, (cx, cy), 5, (0, 0, 255), -1)

    cv2.imshow("bacteriaImg", bacteriaImg)
    cv2.waitKey(0)


# Segment Each Image
for i in range(len(img_files)):
    segment_index(i)
```

Edit #1: Applying frmw42's approach, this image seems to get lost. I have tried adjusting a number of parameters but the image does not seem to show up.

[Bright-Field Image #3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2Ftc8.png)

[image: Bright-Field Image #3]

[Bright-Field Image #4](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1ej0F.png)

[image: Bright-Field Image #4]

Comment: I suggest you show your code and view the images after each step and see where the one bacteria is getting lost. You may be able to adjust some parameter or command to bring that one in.

Comment: @fmw42 I've added my code.

Comment: Did you review the images created after each step to find where the one bacteria is lost? In particular review your threshold result and try changing the arguments. Did you try median filtering or other noise reduction before thresholding? Did you try sharpening before thresholding? What about other kernel shapes or sizes?

Comment: @fmw42 Reviewing the contour images, it seems like the contour fragments in the algorithm, I'll post the image. What arguments do you suggest changing? I'm doing a research project and have never done any computer vision before, I could use some pointers in the right direction.

Comment: Did you look at the result of your thresholding to see if that image looks OK? Is your circular noise filtering damaging your first contour? What about the union and ratio filtering? Are they damaging your result?  Please either view each result or save an image for that result so that you can debug where the issue is arising. Don't just view the final result. View each step.

Comment: @fmw42 I'm pretty sure the idea for the convex hull was for noise reduction, to ensure the contours are close to circular.

Comment: I'll try this to find the source of the problem.

Comment: @fmw42 Unfortunately I can’t seem to find a way to fix this. Would you like to try running the program?

Answer (score 2):

Here is my Python/OpenCV code to extract your bacteria. I simply threshold, then get the contours and draw filled contours for those within a certain area range. I will let you do any further processing that you want. I simply viewed each step to make sure I have tuned the arguments appropriately before moving to the next step.

Input 1:

[image]

Input 2:

[image]

```
import cv2
import numpy as np

# read image
#img = cv2.imread("bacteria1.png")
img = cv2.imread("bacteria2.png")

# convert img to grayscale
gray = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
gray = 255 - gray

# do adaptive threshold on inverted gray image
thresh = cv2.adaptiveThreshold(gray, 255, cv2.ADAPTIVE_THRESH_MEAN_C, cv2.THRESH_BINARY, 21, 5)

result = np.zeros_like(img)
contours = cv2.findContours(thresh , cv2.RETR_EXTERNAL, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)
contours = contours[0] if len(contours) == 2 else contours[1]
for cntr in contours:
    area = cv2.contourArea(cntr)
    if area > 600 and area < 1100:
        cv2.drawContours(result, [cntr], 0, (255,255,255), -1)


# write results to disk
#cv2.imwrite("bacteria_filled_contours1.png", result)
cv2.imwrite("bacteria_filled_contours2.png", result)

# display it
cv2.imshow("thresh", thresh)
cv2.imshow("result", result)
cv2.waitKey(0)
```

Result 1:

[image]

Result 2:

[image]

Adjust as desired.

Comment: Thanks for this! I understand your algorithm, but I'm unable to find a way to make Bright-Field Image #3 appear (It is currently the simplest image to get lost). I've tried playing around with the parameters but it's totally messing it up. I've never done any image processing before so I would highly appreciate your expertise.

Comment: What parameters should I try to optimize? It seems like optimizing for a particular image makes it worse for others.

Comment: This line seems to work for me for all 3 images. `thresh = cv2.adaptiveThreshold(gray, 255, cv2.ADAPTIVE_THRESH_MEAN_C, cv2.THRESH_BINARY, 21, 2)`

Comment: I've been playing around with this. The problem seems to arise when the bacteria are in the process of splitting. Could you take a look at Bright-Field Image #4?

Answer (score 2):

It would seem that adaptive threshold is not able to handle all your various images. I suspect nothing simple will. You may need to use AI with training. Nevertheless, this works for your images: 1, 2 and 4 in Python/OpenCV. I make no guarantee that it will work for any of your other images.

First I found a simple threshold that seems to work, but brings in other regions. So since all your bacteria have similar shapes and range of orientations, I fit and ellipse to your bacteria and get the orientation of the major axis and filter the contours with area and angle.

```
import cv2
import numpy as np

# read image
#img = cv2.imread("bacteria1.png")
#img = cv2.imread("bacteria2.png")
img = cv2.imread("bacteria4.png")

# convert img to grayscale
gray = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
gray = 255 - gray

# median filter
#gray = cv2.medianBlur(gray, 1)

# do simple threshold on inverted gray image
thresh = cv2.threshold(gray, 170, 255, cv2.THRESH_BINARY)[1]

result = np.zeros_like(img)
contours = cv2.findContours(thresh , cv2.RETR_EXTERNAL, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)
contours = contours[0] if len(contours) == 2 else contours[1]
for cntr in contours:
    area = cv2.contourArea(cntr)
    if area > 600 and area < 1100:
        ellipse = cv2.fitEllipse(cntr)
        (xc,yc),(d1,d2),angle = ellipse
        if angle > 90:
            angle = angle - 90
        else:
            angle = angle + 90
        print(angle,area)
        if angle >= 150 and angle <= 250:
            cv2.drawContours(result, [cntr], 0, (255,255,255), -1)
  
# write results to disk
#cv2.imwrite("bacteria_filled_contours1.png", result)
#cv2.imwrite("bacteria_filled_contours2.png", result)
cv2.imwrite("bacteria_filled_contours4.png", result)

# display it
cv2.imshow("thresh", thresh)
cv2.imshow("result", result)
cv2.waitKey(0)
```

Result for image 1:

[image]

Result for image 2:

[image]

Result for image 4:

[image]

You might explore noise reduction before thresholding. I had some success with using some of ImageMagick tools and there is a Python version called Python Wand that uses ImageMagick.